Excel's let function to declare function to search text cell for numbers between min and max
This is something I may need to be more complicated, but nevertheless. My question is how can I optimize my formula to look for a number range between a min and max within a text string cell?
My scenario: I have an item description column, some of which have numbers/dimensions within the text string. I have another column I'm attempting to pull in pricing from another workbook table.
The problem is with any of the descriptions; there may be several numbers/dimensions I need to look between that relate to a single category, which I use in my XLOOKUP to pull pricing from another workbook.
Output Table Example:



Item Description
Price Lookup Return




Product 16x20
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("16",[@Item Description])),XLOOKUP("Small",'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[Product Size],'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[New Price],"",0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("20",[@Item Description])),XLOOKUP("Large",'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[Product Size],'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[New Price],"",0),"")))


Product 16x16
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("16",[@Item Description])),XLOOKUP("Small",'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[Product Size],'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[New Price],"",0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("20",[@Item Description])),XLOOKUP("Large",'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[Product Size],'New Pricing.xlsx'!Table1[New Price],"",0),"")))



The XLOOKUP Table



Product Size
New Price




Small
$350.00


Large
$1260.00



Any help would be appreciated. I was thinking of using Let("MyFucntion" Min/Max, but I am unsure how to implement it.
My "goal" is to find a way to look for any number between a min/max (16-20) within a cell's text. Then, I could look up its price based on the "Product Size" in another table.

To your first row you have 16x20 which have both small and large. In this case which one XLOOKUP() will search?

I would want the "20" to be evaluated at the "large" size. I'm going off my assumption that Excel evaluates the formula from left to right, which seems to be working okay. But there has to be a more efficient way to do this. I have other numbers, like between 36 and 48 and anything larger than 49, that I would like to evaluate.

=IF(ISNUMBER(Find(20,[@Item Description])),"Large","Small")? Else share more examples with expected output.

I would recommend to use FILTERXML() then determine Large or Small and use XLOOKUP().
=LET(SmLrg,MAX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3," ","</s><s>"),"x","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.]")),
XLOOKUP(IF(SmLrg>16,"Large","Small"),$G$4:$G$5,$H$4:$H$5))

FILTERXML() has capability to extract numbers as numeric value and you can apply mathematical functions on those outputs.


Okay, wow, this is over my head. I'll need to look this up and unpack what is happening here. But I like how your example works! I'll try it out sometime tomorrow. Thank you @Harun24hr

@mjl See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747 from JvdV for a clear understanding about FILTERXML().
